# Why are my Outbound URLs in NUnit different from the ones in my View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm reading Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework book.  In an example on 106 - 111 the author walks through creating an NUnit test for a HTMLHelper class.

I noticed that when I ran my HTMLHelper code in NUnit the links appeared like this:

```
<a href="Page1">1</a>
<a class="selected" href="Page2">2</a>
<a href="Page3">3</a>
```

But when I see them in the View they look like this:

```
<a href="/">1</a>
<a class="selected" href="/Page2">2</a>
<a href="/Page3">3</a>
```

**Here's my route code:**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "List", page = 1 }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Page{page}",
    new {controller = "Products",action="List"},
    new {page=@"\d+" }
 );
```

**Helper code**

```
public static string PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, int currentPage, 
    int totalPages, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
    {
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
        tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
        tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
        if (i == currentPage)
            tag.AddCssClass("selected");
        result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());                
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

**View Code**

```
 <%= Html.PageLinks(2,3,i=>Url.Action("List",new {page=i})) %>
```

**test code**

```
string links = ((HtmlHelper)null).PageLinks(2, 3, i => "Page" + i);
            Assert.AreEqual(@"<a href=""Page1"">1</a>
<a class=""selected"" href=""Page2"">2</a>
<a href=""Page3"">3</a>
", links);
```

I understand that the urls are created based on information in my routing table so I'm not sure why the links would be different.  **Does NUnit not have the same perspective that the view does and thus creates different links?  How can I get NUnit to generate the same exact links my View does?**